# Fabric JS - UNDO & REDO optimization using JSON diff

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, canvas, fabricjs

Currently, I have implemented quite standard UNDO and REDO by using listeners to trigger `canvas.getObjects()` whose JSON output I store in a stack.

```
// Canvas modified listeners
canvas?.on('object:modified', onCanvasModifiedHandler)
canvas?.on('object:removed', onCanvasModifiedHandler)
canvas?.on('object:changed', onCanvasModifiedHandler)
```

When the user clicks undo and redo, we fetch JSON representation of the canvas from the stack and loads it using `canvas?.loadFromJSON(json, () => { ... })`

**My problem** is that it is quite inefficient to store the entire JSON representation of the canvas when the actual change is quite small. As a result, this approach causes my application to freeze for *500 milliseconds* when the user clicks UNDO and REDO.

**My proposed solution** is to store only the JSON diff by using for example this package, although it is quite an undertaking. https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsondiffpatch

**My question** is if anyone has had this problem before, and how did you solve it in that case? Or if someone has any other ideas.

Inspired by this thread: https://bountify.co/undo-redo-with-2-canvases-in-fabric-js

Comment: Hi. I agree, a difficult task. It is possible to store not the entire history, but 10 or 20 records.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the command pattern for this. It will be more efficient than using all JSON data. For that, you need to implement the next approach:

1. Create a class for storing History. It maybe looks like this

```
class CommandHistory {
  commands = [];
  index = 0;
  getIndex() {
    return this.index;
  }
  back() {
    if (this.index > 0) {
      let command = this.commands[--this.index];
      command.undo();
    }
    return this;
  }
  forward() {
    if (this.index < this.commands.length) {
      let command = this.commands[this.index++];
      command.execute();
    }
    return this;
  }
  add(command) {
    if (this.commands.length) {
      this.commands.splice(this.index, this.commands.length - this.index);
    }
    this.commands.push(command);
    this.index++;
    return this;
  }
  clear() {
    this.commands.length = 0;
    this.index = 0;
    return this;
  }
}

// use when you init your Canvas, like this.history = new CommandHistory();
```

2. Then you must implement the command classes for your commands.

For adding object

```
class AddCommand {
  constructor(receiver, controller) {
    this.receiver = receiver;
    this.controller = controller;
  }
  execute() {
    this.controller.addObject(this.receiver);
  }
  undo() {
    this.controller.removeObject(this.receiver);
  }
}

// When you will add object on your canvas invoke also this.history.add(new AddCommand(object, controller))
```

For removing object

```
class RemoveCommand {
  constructor(receiver, controller) {
    this.receiver = receiver;
    this.controller = controller;
  }
  execute() {
    this.controller.removeObject(this.receiver);
  }
  undo() {
    this.controller.addObject(this.receiver);
  }
}
```

The fabric.js has the saveState method for every object http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#saveState. And you can use it for implementing the transform command, which will be added to the history object when you will modify your fabric object on the canvas.

```
class TransformCommand {
  constructor(receiver, options = {}) {
    this.receiver = receiver;
    this._initStateProperties(options);

    this.state = {};
    this.prevState = {};

    this._saveState();
    this._savePrevState();
  }
  execute() {
    this._restoreState();
    this.receiver.setCoords();
  }
  undo() {
    this._restorePrevState();
    this.receiver.setCoords();
  }
  // private
  _initStateProperties(options) {
    this.stateProperties = this.receiver.stateProperties;
    if (options.stateProperties && options.stateProperties.length) {
      this.stateProperties.push(...options.stateProperties);
    }
  }
  _restoreState() {
    this._restore(this.state);
  }
  _restorePrevState() {
    this._restore(this.prevState);
  }
  _restore(state) {
    this.stateProperties.forEach((prop) => {
      this.receiver.set(prop, state[prop]);
    });
  }
  _saveState() {
    this.stateProperties.forEach((prop) => {
      this.state[prop] = this.receiver.get(prop);
    });
  }
  _savePrevState() {
    if (this.receiver._stateProperties) {
      this.stateProperties.forEach((prop) => {
        this.prevState[prop] = this.receiver._stateProperties[prop];
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can add your commands to your history and execute or undo them.

Comment: Thank you for you answer @Raman, I will try out this solution once I have cleared some of my current tasks. Have you tried out this solution and seen its performance yourself?

Comment: yes, I have, of course, it was taken from an existing project an I can share it

Comment: This is nice, quick question, why do we store the `prevState` when we can do `command.execute()` or `this.commands[--this.index].execute()` to be specific?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this solution also stores all `object properties` and not only the `diffs` between states?

Comment: Yes we stores values of all object properties, current and prev, probably you’re right and you can try to do like you suggested

Comment: Hi, @RamanNikitsenka. Good idea. Can you see a working version somewhere?

Comment: @RamanNikitsenka, интересное решение ) Спасибо.